# why the iteration is done by i+6 every time and why the condition is i*i<=n for this prime testing function?

Tags: c++, primality-test

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-1-introduction-and-school-method/

// A optimized school method based C++ program to check 
// if a number is prime

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

bool isPrime(int n) 
{ 
    // Corner cases 
    if (n <= 1)  return false; 
    if (n <= 3)  return true; 

    // This is checked so that we can skip  
    // middle five numbers in below loop 
    if (n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false; 

    for (int i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+6) 
        if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0) 
           return false; 

    return true; 
}
```

Comment: The link explains why it increments by 6.  I'll leave it to you to answer: Can a factor of a number be larger than it's square root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search for primes you can loop through all the numbers between 2 and your number to see if they divide into your number.

```
for (int i=2; i < n; i=i+1) 
    if (n%i == 0)
       return false;
```

But that checks a lot of number you don't need to.
The first observation (optimization) is that any multiple of 2 (even number) is already checked by simply doing a divide by 2 check once.

So now we do a check for 2 and then skip every other even character.

```
if (n%2 == 0 ) return false;

for (int i=3; i < n; i=i+2) 
    if (n%i == 0)
       return false;
```

The next observation (optimization) is that you can do nearly the same thing for three. So the first test covers all combinations of 2 and three. Now in the loop you skip every 6 numbers (2*3) and do some tests to cover all numbers that are not multiples of 2 or 3 that happen in between.

```
if (n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false; 

for (int i=5; i<n; i=i+6) 
    if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0) 
       return false;
```

So this is simply an optimization that means you do not have to try every number.

The next observation we make is that you don't need to try numbers greater than the square root of n (these will never divide into n). So you can limit your loop to `i*i < n` as `i*i` is faster than `sqrt(n)`.

```
if (n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false; 

for (int i=5; i*i<=n; i=i+6) 
    if (n%i == 0 || n%(i+2) == 0) 
       return false;
```

Though personally I would do `sqrt()` once rather than `i*i` every time around the loop. But that may be slower for small values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Any number that is composite will have at least one factor that is less than or equal to its square root. Why? Because if it has only a single factor (other than itself or one), that will be equal to its square root. If it has two or more, the smallest one will have to be less than its square root. So no need to check numbers greater than the square root -- if it wasn't prime, we would have already found a factor.

The code checks for 2 or 3 as a factor early. After that, we only need to check for factors that aren't multiples of two or three. So after we check 5 and 7, we don't need to check 6, 8, 9, or 10. So out of every six numbers we only need to check the two that aren't multiples of two or three.